# Cipher method not supported on laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I have a project that I want to build an api auth as a part of it, so i have read the Laravel Passport Article: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport as a quick start to do so.

I followed the guide until requesting token. Here is a route which will redirect back to server for authentication:

```
Route::get(‘/redirect’, function () {
$query = http_build_query([
‘client_id’ => ‘client-id’,
‘redirect_uri’ => ‘http://example.com/callback’,
‘response_type’ => ‘code’,
‘scope’ => ”,
]);

return redirect(‘http://your-app.com/oauth/authorize?’.$query);
});
```

Here is the redirect URL:

http://myapp.dev/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.dev%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=

Once the URL had been visited, a permission page will show up asking me to approve the request.

Once I clicked “Authorize” button, the page shows the following error message:

"Cipher method not supported. This is normally caused by an outdated version of OpenSSL (and/or OpenSSL compiled for FIPS compliance). Please upgrade to a newer version of OpenSSL that supports aes-256-ctr to use this library."

I'm using MAMP 3.5 on macOS Seirra.

openssl version OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

openssl ciphers DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-MD5:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA:SEED-SHA:RC2-CBC-MD5:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:RC4-MD5:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5

I've upgraded openssl from 0.9.8zh to 1.0.2l throw brew command, but I could not link it to be the default openssl.

I have been stuck in this page for one day now. Hope anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do all that using `https`?

Comment: Thank you for your engagement. I fixed the issue by installing MAMP PRO 4.x. It seems that openssl supporting a new protocol and Cipher Algorithms was integrated in this version. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing MAMP PRO 4.x

Thanks